# Rails, Postgres: dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _PQresultMemorySize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, macos

creating a new rails-app (6.0.2) with postgres, on mac, could not get it to run.

Getting this error on app start:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _PQresultMemorySize
  Referenced from: /Users/dev/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/pg-1.2.2/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

[image]

This seems to be similar to [dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _PQresultMemorySize - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59772466/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-pqresultmemorysize-rails),

but what is to do?

My previous rails apps, on rails v6.0.1, also with the same postgres `gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'` are running just fine

Comment: Found out very easy way to solve the issue. Just need to uninstall `pg` gem and then re-install it.
1. `gem uninstall pg`
2. `bundle install` or `gem install pg`
And lastly don't forget to stop if any spring process is running in your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following workaround. It hardcodes the path to the shared library in the pg_ext.bundle:

```
install_name_tool -change libpq.5.dylib /Library/PostgreSQL/12/lib/libpq.5.12.dylib pg_ext.bundle
```

Comment: Thanks, Roman, worked for me! (cd to gem-path and your command) - now i can work with pg 1.2.3. Hope, that the postgres-people fix this annoying error

Comment: I got an error.

error: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/install_name_tool: can't open file: pg_ext.bundle (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 28):

What solved my issue was to run a `gem uninstall pg` and after that do the `bundle install`

Answer (score 6):

`PQresultMemorySize` was introduced in postgres 12, since 1.2.0 `pg` gem checks if it is available during extension build and uses if it is (previously it did not). Since it was available at build, and you probably have not downgraded postgres or libpq right away - it suggests some version conflict.

When installing from homebrew location would be `/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib`, but you have `/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib`
Looks like you have libpq from/and postgres >= 12 installed together with some older version.

You need to find which different postgresses/libpq you have installed and remove one of these to get rid of the conflict.

As a temporary solution - you can set `pg` version requirement to be exactly the same as your already working one (look into Gemfile.lock of the other app), so that already installed gem will be used (and have more correct extension or just be a version that does not try to access this new feature yet).

Comment: Thanks Vasfed! since then it ran, i cannot say why, but since today i have the same issue. yesterday it worked, today not. i think you're right. i wanted to `ln -s /Library/PostgreSQL/12/lib/libpq.5.12.dylib /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib` but now i have this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60395302/mac-mojave-permissions-in-usr-lib. for now i made `gem 'pg', '~> 1.1.4'` in my Gemfile and it works for now ...

Answer (score 5):

Okay, team — here’s what I did.

First, I ran into this issue upgrading from `postgresql` 12 to 13 via homebrew ... because I am an idiot and didn’t pin 12.

After fixing a bunch of issues, all seemed to be functioning (I could boot my server, I could reinstall the `pg` gem — all seemed to be good). I had gotten the `/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib` error reinstalling `pg` early on ... but then it magically went away and I thought I was golden. I wasn’t. When I ran my Rails console, I ran a query and ... got the `/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib` error.

What did work was:

1. `brew services stop postgresql`
2. `brew install libpq`
3. `brew link --overwrite libpq --force`
4. `brew services start postgresql`

For those of you running `spring`, don’t forget to `spring stop` (I’m not sure the order really matters, and it’s also possible stopping/restarting `postgresql` wasn’t necessary, but better safe than sorry).

Comment: This worked for me, Rails 6.1.3

Answer (score 3):

Rebuilding the gem worked for me:

```
gem pristine pg
```

Comment: This is one of the easier solution.

Comment: Great. This did the job.

Answer (score 2):

next attempt for solution:

`$ gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_config` according to [github-pg](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg#how-to-install-)

```
Fetching: pg-1.2.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions with: '--with-pg-config=/Library/PostgreSQL/12/bin/pg_config'
This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-1.2.2
Parsing documentation for pg-1.2.2
Installing ri documentation for pg-1.2.2
Done installing documentation for pg after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Gemfile:
`gem 'pg', '~> 1.2.2'`

[same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5DIP.png)

pg searches for `/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib`, and there is a symlink, but it seems to point to the older version of postgres.

for me, it seems, that it should look for `/Library/PostgreSQL/12/lib/libpq.5.dylib`

how to teach the gem for looking to that dylib?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the steps I did to solve this issue was:

1. **gem uninstall pg** - you might receive a message saying:

```
pg is not installed in GEM_HOME, try:
    gem uninstall -i /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0 pg
```

If that happens, execute the suggested path with sudo:

```
sudo gem uninstall -i /Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0 pg
```

2. if you run **bundle install** might result in an error saying "*An error occurred while installing pg (1.2.3), and Bundler cannot continue.*". Install postgres:

```
brew install postgresql
```

or

```
gem install pg -v '1.2.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/
```

3. Proceed with rails command as in my case:

```
rails db:setup
```